# Access pixels of 24-bit bitmap, without using GetPixel()?

Tags: windows, winapi, colors, bitmap, gdi

I am currently looking for a way to access and test the individual pixels of a copied bitmap from a target window, without using the very slow `GetPixel()` method.  Given that `memDC` contains a copy of the bitmap at the moment that `BitBlt()` was called, is there a faster way to traverse the individual pixels and test their values?

```
HWND target = (HWND)0x0002051A; // this is just for debugging; when i get to the release version it will detect the intended window automatically
HBITMAP hBitmap;
RECT winRect;
HDC winDC, memDC;
winDC = GetDC(target);
GetClientRect(target, &winRect);
memDC = CreateCompatibleDC(winDC);
hBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(winDC, winRect.right-winRect.left, winRect.bottom-winRect.top);
SelectObject(memDC, hBitmap);
BitBlt(memDC, 0, 0, winRect.right-winRect.left, winRect.bottom-winRect.top, winDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
// Perform other tasks based on the color values of pixels...
ReleaseDC(memDC);
ReleaseDC(winDC);
DeleteObject(hBitmap);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create the target bitmap with `CreateDIBSection` you can get access to the raw pixels rather than having to go through `GetPixel`.

E.g. if the `BITMAPINFO` you pass specifies a 32-bpp image (the simplest format to interpret), you could access an arbitrary pixel using something like `*( ((LPDWORD)pBits) + ( y * width ) + x)`.

See the docs for `BITMAPINFOHEADER` for details of how the different bitdepth formats are laid out in memory, and remember a) that bitmap rows are always DWORD aligned, and b) you need to pass a negative height to create a top-down bitmap.

And if you don't or can't use `CreateDIBSection`, you can use [`GetDIBits`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144879%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get an in-memory copy of the bitmap in the DIB format you desire.  (Make sure the bitmap is selected out of any DC before calling `GetDIBits`.)